# Unable to fetch SharePoint Search File filter through HTTPS (Only HTTP works)

Tags: javascript, search, sharepoint, server, sharepoint-online

I am currently facing an issue where my file type cannot be retrieved via HTTPS when using the SharePoint Search File filter however it can be downloaded via HTTP. Is there a workaround for this? Currently I cannot replicate this piece of code as it is within an internal server.

Please do assist and any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

**Filter**

> const searchURL = "http://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext='fileType:pptx'"

If I were to use HTTPS for the filter it would return an error.

> GET "https://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27fileType:pptx%27"
> **net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Filters</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: black; color: aliceblue;" >
    <h1 style="color: darkmagenta;">Search Queries</h1>
   
    <button id="powerpointButton">Search PowerPoint</button>
   
    <h2>Search Results:</h2>
    <div id="results" style="color:aliceblue !important"></div>
   
    <script>
        async function testFilter(searchURL) {
            const xhr1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr1.open("GET", searchURL);
            xhr1.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json;odata=verbose");

            xhr1.onreadystatechange = async function () {
                if (xhr1.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr1.status === 200) {
                        const response = JSON.parse(xhr1.responseText);
                        console.log(`XHR1 Success!!`, response);

                        // Extract URLs of document files from the response
                        const results = response.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;
                        const resultsDiv = document.getElementById("results");
                        resultsDiv.innerHTML = "";

                        for (const result of results) {
                            const extension = result.Cells.results.find(cell => cell.Key === 'FileExtension').Value;
                            if (extension && extension.toLowerCase() !== 'aspx') {
                                const title = result.Cells.results.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Title').Value;
                                const url = result.Cells.results.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Path').Value.replace("https://", "http://");

                                resultsDiv.innerHTML += `<p><a href='${url}'>${title}</a></p>`;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.error('XHR1 Error:', xhr1.statusText);
                    }
                }
            };
            xhr1.send();
        }

        document.getElementById("powerpointButton").addEventListener("click", function() {
            const searchURL = "http://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext='fileType:pptx'";
            testFilter(searchURL);
        });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**HTTP** Error:
The file at *'http://www.test.com/Shared%20Documents/2%20Test%20Powerpoint.pptx'* was loaded over an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS.

**HTTPS** Error:
*'https://www.test.com/Shared%20Documents/2%20Test%20Powerpoint.pptx'*
This site cannot be reached.